# Linux doesn't boot: I changed the location of usr/sbin

Tags: linux, files, permissions, linux-mint

*This is a follow up to my previous question but I will explain it better here, since I now know exactly the problem.*

EDIT: The command that screw everything up: `/usr sudo mv sbin local`

I accidentally sent the usr/sbin folder to the path usr/local/sbin. That's when the system crashed. 
I restarted the pc and I saw that the systems asked me again and again to instert my password.
Attempting to fix the problem I tried to install lightdm, but it made the problem even worse, since now the system does not boot: I the Linux Mint logo was refreshing for ever and I couldn't even go to the login page.

So the folder system is as follows (how the path was, and how it is now):

1. **/usr/sbin** is now at **/usr/local/sbin**
2. **/usr/local/sbin** is now at **/home/sbin**
3. There is a NEW sbin folder at **usr/sbin** path, that contains guest-acc, lightdm, lightdm-session.
4. **/sbin** is still at **/sbin**

I tried to move /usr/local/sbin (the original /usr/sbin) to it's original path, but it asked me to change some permissions (775?). I said no, since I do not want to make the situation worse.

EDIT: I can boot the system only from recovery mode, so I can boot it only with terminal

Comment: Short answer, boot from a USB stick, backup your home dir to an external disk and then wipe the machine and start again is probably the simplest approach.

Comment: Isn't there a way to try to put the /usr/sbin to its original path and see what if it's fixed? My problem with that is that It will overwrite the /usr/sbin of lightdm, but I'm not sure if i even need that.

Comment: While yes it may be possible to "fix" this, without a detailed understanding of what's going on, my first suggestion is going to be the quickest way to get you a working system. You are much more likely to just break it more trying to fix it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is there a way to save a particular program in the system?

Comment: @hardillb Surely you can compare the broken system with a fresh one, see whats wrong and fix things like that. Reinstall is the worst option, losing all programs, config, etc.

Comment: But it doesn't sound like the OP has a working system to compare to. All the user settings should be in the home dir I suggested backing up first. Reinstalling packages after the fresh install should be pretty quick, that's what package managers are good at.

Comment: I can compare it with a fresh ubuntu system, but it will not be mint. That's how I saw what changed with all the sbins

Comment: If you do not know what went wrong, you may miss certain problems that need fixing, and those problems will pop-up at the least convenient moment. Backup and re-install is your safest solution. If possible: backup the whole disk, not just your home-dir.

Comment: will the programs be saved that way?
I will edit now the post, because I found exactly the command that screw the system up